# Gradle - get dependency list for each library/module

Tags: maven, gradle, groovy

I am trying to get the dependencies list for each modules/library in a project.

Here is the structure of the project:

```
Project
+ --- library1
     + --- library2
        + --- library3
     + --- library4
        + --- library3
```

The build.gradle of ***project*** is

```
dependencies {
     compile project(':library1')
}
```

library2 and library4 all depend on library3. and the way they compile dependencies are the same with ***project***.

I would want to get the dependencies for each modules/libraries so that i can decide the sequence of bumping version for these libraries and uploading to maven in a script file.

So I would first want to save these dependencies for each module in a variable and the script file can read it and do the automation work.

I have tried using Conifguration.getAllDependencies() in custom gradle build file. But it doesnt work.

Anyone know how would I do that?
Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

====
UPDATE:

I have tried adding a task under project's gradle file

```
List<ProjectDependency> dependencies =
        project.configurations.collectMany {
            it.allDependencies
        }.findAll {
            it instanceof ProjectDependency
        }
```

But the dependencies returns 0 size of list

Answer (score 1):

- For a simple project, one can get its dependencies by invoking

```
project.configurations*.
        dependencies*.
        findAll { it instanceof ExternalDependency }.
        flatten()
```

Note that `ExternalDependency`, not `ProjectDependency` is used.

- For dealing with dependencies on a real project, [gradle-versions-plugin by Ben Manes](https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin) offers some nice reports
- [gradle-dependency-lock plugin by Netflix](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-dependency-lock-plugin) provides dependency update automation